# Checking if in-app purchases are owned in Android on first launch

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing

I am trying to detect if any of the in-app purchases are owned by the user when the app is started on first try to renew the Pro mode of the app using SharedPreferences. The following code is unfortunately not working :(

```
        if (version.equals("null")) { //checking version of the app, if it is unset equals first launch
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appinfo.edit();
        version = currentversion;
        editor.putString("version", version);
        editor.apply();

        IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
                = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                                 Inventory inventory) {

                if (mHelper == null) return; //IabHelper mHelper;
                Purchase purchase = Inventory.getPurchase("sku1");
                Purchase purchase2 = Inventory.getPurchase("sku2");
                Purchase purchase3 = Inventory.getPurchase("sku3");
                if (purchase != null || purchase2 != null || purchase3 != null) {
                    final SharedPreferences ispro = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ispro", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ispro.edit();
                    editor.putInt("ispro", 1);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        };

        startActivity(new Intent(MainPage.this, Changelog.class));
```

EDIT1: After some edits the code now looks like this:

```
final List<String> skus = Arrays.asList("sku1", "sku2", "sku3");
    if (version.equals("null")) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appinfo.edit();
        version = currentversion;
        editor.putString("version", version);
        editor.apply();

        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {

                }


                if (mHelper == null) return;

                mBroadcastReceiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver(MainPage.this);
                IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
                registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);

                IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
                        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
                    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                                         Inventory inventory) {
                        if (mHelper == null) return;
                        Purchase purchase = Inventory.getPurchase("sku1");
                        Purchase purchase2 = Inventory.getPurchase("sku2");
                        Purchase purchase3 = Inventory.getPurchase("sku3");
                        if (purchase != null || purchase2 != null || purchase3 != null) {
                            final SharedPreferences ispro = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ispro", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ispro.edit();
                            editor.putInt("ispro", 1);
                            editor.apply();
                        }
                    }
                };

                try {
                     mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skus, null, mReceivedInventoryListener);
                } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {

                }
            }
        });

        startActivity(new Intent(MainPage.this, Changelog.class));
```

I am not aware what is wrong with this code. Thank you in advance for the help and Happy New Year! :)

Comment: Did you ever call `IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync()`? Also, If `Changelog` checks `ispro` as soon as it starts, it may not see the correct value because `onQueryInventoryFinished()` does not necessarily execute before the call to `startActivity()`; it is asynchronous.

Comment: `Changelog` is page showing what is new in this version, in this case it will be replaced with Welcome screen. It does not check `ispro`. I tried to query Invenotry - `IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, "sku1", mReceivedInventoryListener);` before  the code related to the check is executed as shown in other [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417314/android-check-if-in-app-purchase-was-bought-before), but `mReceivedInventoryListener` cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync()` in order for a `QueryInventoryFinishedListener` to do anything useful. Just add a call to that function immediately prior to your `startActivity()` call. (This is assuming you've already called `IabHelper.startSetup()` and all that good stuff first.)

You cannot refer to a local variable prior to its declaration. The reason you got a "mReceivedInventoryListener cannot be resolved" error is because the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34417434/6759241) referenced in your example swapped the two lines in a confusing way.

Obligatory mention: `IabHelper` is apparently no longer supported by Google; you're supposed to use the [billing client library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I edited the post above to show the changes I've made. The app now crashes on startup and I do not know the exact reason. I will consider moving to Billing Client Library in the near future. :)

Comment: @KrumCvetkov if the question changes enough, [you should ask a new one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions). Right now that's my opinion on this one. Let me give you this advice: Always include the stacktrace associated with the crash. You can find it in logcat. And try to determine on your own which parts of the program are executing -- either through `Log` statements, or (preferably) via the debugger, and include that information as well.

Comment: I solved the problem! The problem was that `IabHelper` was undefined and lacked the 64-bit key, so the app crashed. Everything is working excellent now. Again thank you very much for the help, without you I wouldn't be able to make it work. :)